# Save the present state of GUI created using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a GUI using tkinter and was thinking that when I exit the GUI, it should save the present state of the GUI and upon opening it, the saved state to be reloaded.
Is there any command to do that?
Thanks in advance :)

I have mentioned above too, that the example given in that question(stackoverflow.com/questions/33553200/save-and-load-gui-tkinter) doesn't work. It doesn't save the state and gives the error-- 
**error loading saved state: 'str' does not support the buffer interface**

```
def one(self):
    Button1=Button(self,text="Button1")
    Button1.grid(column=0,row=0)
    Button2.=Button(self,text="Button2",command=self.entry1)
    Button2.grid(column=0,row=1)

def entry1(self):
    self.entry=Entry(self)
    self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0)
```

This is just an example-
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: check this link-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553200/save-and-load-gui-tkinter

Comment: That example doesn't work. I am so badly stuck

Comment: I have mentioned above too, that the example given in that question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553200/save-and-load-gui-tkinter) doesn't work. It doesn't save the state and gives the error-- error loading saved state: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Answer (score 1):

I'd iterate over every object, serialize it, and save this in a db upon closing the application, probably naming the session after the saving date.

```
for child in frame.children.values():
    #serialize and store child somewhere
```

Comment: Will you please give me an example.

Comment: sure, share your code.

Comment: I have edited my question and I have pasted the code too

Comment: Is there any way of doing it @Loic

Comment: this is marked as duplicate, it means the answer is in the linked similar question. If it is not, please remove the duplicate status.