# Saving and Loading the GUI of a complex tkinter application

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, serialization, pickle

I have a very complex tkinter application, it's an editor, for now it's not so much different than window's notepad but it will have tons of functions that it doesn't. The problem is that i didn't correctly understand the way used to save the gui in this topic:

[Save and Load GUI-tkinter - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553200/save-and-load-gui-tkinter)

For example why `save_state(self)` isn't defined in `Example(tk.Frame)` and why even the class is a frame? Mine is a `Tk()` widget can that method work with it? Also doesn't functions need to be called how they are working without calling? and could you tell wha are doing `"previous":`, `"expression":`, `"result":`in this part? :

```
def save_state(self):
        try:
            data = {
                "previous": self.previous_values,
                "expression": self.expressionVar.get(),
                "result": self.resultLabel.cget("text"),
            }
            with open(FILENAME, "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(data, f)

        except Exception as e:
            print
            "error saving state:", str(e)
```

Here is my code:

[My editor](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pTa37-Fv1qiKDyzDMKYRtoYonENwVKYf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please do not forget that it has menu options to save too

Comment: are you trying to save only the text?

Comment: of course no, i am trying to add a function like this to mine

Comment: You don't have any classes so what are you trying to save?

Comment: i think if i just can learn how to save Stringvariables to a class or even without a class i can do it also i've asked some questions up there

Comment: @JacksonPro u here?

Comment: are you trying to save the state of Text widget?

Comment: What do you mean by _"For example why save_state(self) isn't defined in Example(tk.Frame) "_? It _is_ defined as part of `Example`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't worry about the code in the example, and instead focus on the *concept*. You need to write two functions: one to save the data and one to restore the data.

The function to save the data must gather then data into some sort of data structure. The code you linked to chose a simple dictionary of values that is pickled.  You could use a sqlite database, a yaml file, a dictionary, a custom object, whatever you want.

The function to restore the data must read the data in at startup, and then put the data back into the appropriate widgets.

For a text editor, you're probably going to want to save the names of the open files. So, your "save" function can simply write the list of filenames to a file. Your "reload" function needs to read the list of filenames, and for each file it can open up a tab in your editor.

The only other thing you need to do is arrange for the "save" function to be called on exit. If you have a function to exit the program you can add it there. In the code you linked to, it arranged for the function to be called automatically when the program exits by doing `root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.save_state)`.